# MultiDex with different productFlavors confuse

Tags: android

I am enabling multidex feature on my app, according to [this official post of Google](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html#mdex-gradle), I make two productFlavors with different minSdkVersion as below:

```
 productFlavors {
    A {
        minSdkVersion 21
    }
    B {
        minSdkVersion 14
    }
  }
```

Everything is OK When I build task "BDebug" and install the app.

**But,**  when I build the app with A flavor (ADebug), I got ClassDefNotFound error. **Another weird thing is there is no "multi-dex" folder under "output/intermediates"**.

I am very confused about this, can someone help me ? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Android Api lvl 21 and above default support multidex. If you want use multidex on Api lvl below 21 try to add `compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'` to your dependence. More informations [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html).

Comment: I add this to my dependency. So you mean this is not needed for level >= 21.

Comment: Yes, I know. But can you explain more to me the reason about my question? And how to fix? many thanks.